# Carbon::now() is not using UTC

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, timestamp, php-carbon

I am from Philippines. If ever I will use Carbon::now(), it catches my machine time and not the UTC time.

My config/app.php is:

```
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

This is my code:

```
$log->dateRequest = Carbon::now();
```

If ever I will post a request at 9:00pm (Philippine time). It catches 21:00:00 , instead of 13:00:00 (from UTC).

Answer (score 33):

In one of you questions you mentioned that you need to use multiple timezones in your app. So, you can add timezone dynamically:

```
Carbon::now('UTC')
```

Or use `setTimezone('UTC')` method on existing date.

Answer (score 8):

As stated in [Carbon docs instantiation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), try this:

> $log->dateRequest =  Carbon::now('UTC');

Comment: I tried that at 12:21 am (Philippine time), but I got this 2016-11-25 00:21:23. It should be at 16:21:00 if it's converted in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Carbon uses the default **DateTime** PHP object.

Gets the default timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_get();
// or
Carbon::now()->timezoneName;
```

Sets the default timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

var_dump(Carbon::now()->utc); // true;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
$log->dateRequest = Carbon::now('GMT+8')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Asia/Manila')
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('F j, Y g:i:a', date('F j, Y g:i:a'));

dd($date->format('F j, Y g:i:a')); //  November 27, 2020 11:53:pm
```